# Adding capability to run Eclipse plugin headless

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on an Eclipse plug-in that parses an open Java project and makes changes to the source code. The plug-in works within Eclipse's UI and has buttons and menu options.
I wish to add a headless capability to the plug-in, which would allow running the plug-in from command line, enabling the plug-in to receive input from the command line, use Eclipse's capabilities to analyze the source code and make the necessary changes, and then print some execution information back to the user.

There are a lot of outdated guides on Google that explain how to do it with old versions of Eclipse, however they don't work anymore. Can anyone explain how to add such capabilities to a plug-on project?

Comment: NOTE: I reviewed a lot of questions here on SO and searched Google and I could not find anything that had worked for me. This is not a duplicate question

Comment: There has not been any change in how Eclipse headless code works so those 'outdated guides' are probably still correct. Show us what you tried.

Comment: The general mechanism is to split you plugin into core and ui plugins. Make sure that the core plugin only has dependencies on other core plugins and you should be able to run in headless.